# Magento pdf multiple image print issue

Tags: magento-1.7

I am having trouble while printing multiple images in pdf document , the following code i am using to print the image on pdf , it always printing the last order's image, lets say i have 3 orders , the id of the order is 0000001,0000002,0000003 , now in foreach loop in every iteration it prints the last order id's image 0000003. although my code is in loop

```
foreach ($orders as $order)
    {   
    /* Barcode start here */    

        $image = Mage::helper('barcode/barcode')->createOrderBarcode($order->getRealOrderId());             
        if (is_file($image)) {
                    //Barcode width               
                    $barcode_width = 115; //set default               
                    $barcode_height = 40; //set default
               $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($image);
                    //order padding left
                    $padding_left = 0; //set default
                    //order padding top               
                    $padding_top = 0; //set default
                 // BOTTOM RIGHT
                    $top = 805;
                    $left = 382 - $padding_left;
                //image, left, top, width, height
                $barcode_top = $top - $barcode_height ;
                // $barcode_top = $top - $barcode_height + 6;
                $pdf->drawImage($image, $left, $barcode_top, $left + $barcode_width, $top);
            }
    /* Barcode ends here */
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your code, you are drawing all the images at the same place.
`padding_left` is always 0
`$left` is always 382,  (382 - `$padding_left`)
`$top` is always 805,
`$barcode_height` is always 40
`$barcode_top` is always 765 (`$top` - `$barcode_height`)
So all your images are stacked up one on top of each other.